# Photoshop CS5 scale transparency grid

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency

In all other versions of PS I have used the grey and white transparency grid that shows through transparent images has remained at the same scale when zooming in and out.

The problem I am having is that when working on small images 16x16px the grid is massive, as it has increased in scale as I zoomed in.

There is an option in edit > preferences > Transparency & grid to make it smaller, but my question is; is it posible to fix the grid as it was in previous versions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the official [Photoshop Forum](http://feedback.photoshop.com/photoshop_family/topics/transparency_grid_scales_with_image_pixels), this is an issue with OpenGL acceleration.

To fix it, go to "Edit > Preferences > Performance..." and either set OpenGL Mode to "Normal" or "Advanced" in "GPU Settings panel > Advanced Settings..." , or (in case these options are greyed out like on my machine) disable OpenGL Drawing by unchecking the checkbox in the GPU Settings panel.

Photoshop may need a restart for these changes to take effect.

Answer (score 2):

No idea why you're getting this. The transparency grid stays exactly the same size for me in CS5, no matter how big the image, or how far I zoom in.

My settings (which are default) read:

- Gridsize: Medium
- Grid colors: Light

That's all there is. No idea why it might be different for you. Hope that helps, either way.

Comment: Those look like the settings from the "Grids" preferences, not the "Transparency" preferences?

Comment: Bah, good point. Fixed.

Comment: +1 for your help. What OS are you on?

Comment: No probs. I'm on a PC, but something like this shouldn't be any different on OSX.

Answer (score 0):

That 'defect' happens in rgb mode only. Goto Image->Mode and change to Lab, but you may lose color data

Comment: The accepted answer shows the correct solution to this problem. Why would anybody want to use your solution which potentially loses data?